# Send email to single user in loop

Tags: php, email, yii, smtp

I am trying to send bulk email with php yii . and i am using yii extension Smtpmail. Problem is when i am selecting more than one recipient. it is sending email to all . i mean it is adding in the "To". But if i am using simple mail function it is working properly . and email is going individuals. here is my code

```
$sent=$this->sendbulkemail($inv->to_email,UserModule::t("invitation from {site_name}",array('{site_name}'=>Yii::app()->name)),UserModule::t($template,array('{msg}'=>$msg,'{link}'=>$link)));
```

and my email function is

```
public function sendbulkemail($email,$subject,$message)
    {
        $adminEmail = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);
       // $mail2 = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object

        $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
        $mail->SetFrom($adminEmail, 'Goal Surf');
        $mail->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->AddAddress($email, "");
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

        $mail->Send();
        unset($mail);
    }
```

But if i am using simple `mail()` it is working fine.

```
$sent=mail($inv->to_email,UserModule::t("invitation from {site_name}",array('{site_name}'=>Yii::app()->name)),UserModule::t($template,array('{msg}'=>$msg,'{link}'=>$link)),$headers);
```

anybody please tell me how to do this .

**Update**
[image]

Comment: Is your sendbulkemail function called in loop?

Comment: yes its in foreach loop .

Comment: If you are passing single mail at a time then how can it merge all emails in "To"?

Comment: thats what i am thinking . idk what is the problem

Comment: Can you post your foreach loop?

Comment: i think `$mail->AddAddress($email, "");` is the problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105526/discussion-between-ravi-hirani-and-showstopper).

Comment: @RaviHirani thanks dude for your efforts..

Comment: Welcome Brother :-)  I am glad you have resolved it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue . i just need to use `$mail->ClearAddresses();` to clear the addresses after email success .

```
public function sendbulkemail($email,$subject,$message)
    {
        $adminEmail = Yii::app()->params['adminEmail'];
        $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
        $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $message);
       // $mail2 = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object

        $mail=Yii::app()->Smtpmail;
        $mail->SetFrom($adminEmail, '');
        $mail->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->AddAddress($email, "");
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Send();
        $mail->ClearAddresses();
    }
```